# Geometry Nodes Bezier

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I have made at random looking bezier curve with geometry nodes. But when I take an object and add the Curve modifier, and select the bezier curve as Curve Object, it won't follow that curve. Follow Path doesn't work either.. It seems like the bezier coming from the geometry nodes isn't really a curve. Is there a way to make this curve a real curve that can be used to follow and use with Curve modifier?

Comment: I'm no geometry guru, but did you add a Realize Instances node to it anywhere to make it a 'real' object?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but it didn't do any difference unfortunately.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE! Unfortunately, there is currently no way to create Bezier curves with *Geometry Nodes* that you can process as such afterwards.